# Is Chaining Converters possible in MVVMCross?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Is it possible to somehow chain multiple converters in MVVMCross?

e.g.

```
"ItemsSource Items, Converter=FilterInactive,GroupByDate,SortByType"
```

Or will I have to create a new converter type for each chaining variant I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Tibet Binding syntax you can do:

```
   ItemsSource SortByType(GroupByDate(FilterInactive(Items)))
```

But this might not be the most efficient way to present your data.